# React Native Android Build Error: "cannot find symbol ReactNativeFlipper"

Tags: android, react-native

I'm encountering a build error when attempting to bundle my React Native app for release on Android. The error message is:

```
E:\web-projects\CSR\android\app\src\main\java\com\csr\ratingapp\MainApplication.java:60: error: cannot find symbol
 ReactNativeFlipper.initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
 ^
 symbol:  variable ReactNativeFlipper
 location: class MainApplication
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

I've tried running both **npx react-native run-android --mode=release** and **gradlew bundleRelease** but the error persists.

Here's what I've already tried:
**gradlew clean**

When I run **npx react-native run-android** it does install the app on my phone with no issues arising.

I'm hoping to achieve the following:

Understand the cause of the "cannot find symbol ReactNativeFlipper" error.
Resolve the error and successfully bundle my app for release.

Comment: kindly share your `MainApplication.java` for better understanding and also clear are you using third party `react-native-flipper`  library or not?